# iOS 10 Proactive App Suggestions are Missing

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, ios

Now that I've upgraded my iPhone SE to iOS 10 (version 10.0.2), the proactive app suggestions are gone.

What I mean by *proactive app suggestions*: in iOS 9, when I'd plug in my headphones or connect a bluetooth speaker, a small gray app icon would appear in the lower left of the lock screen or, in the app switcher, a gray app suggestion tab would appear along the bottom of the screen. This would usually be exactly the app I'd want to start using on my iPhone.

The proactive app suggestions feature was very handy. I wish it still existed in iOS 10. Is there a way to turn it back on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to re-enable the proactive app suggestions in iOS 10:

- Go to **Settings** → **General** → **Spotlight Search**
- Turn off the top three options:

  - *Siri Suggestions*
  - *Suggestions in Search*
  - *Suggestions in Look Up*
- Go back to the main **Settings** menu.
- Close the **Settings** app (go to the Home Screen).
- Lock the phone (turn off the screen by quickly pressing and releasing the Sleep/Wake button).
- Unlock the phone.
- Go back to **Settings** → **General** → **Spotlight Search**
- Turn *on* the three options you turned off above.
- Lock the phone (turn off the screen).

Now, when I plug in headphones or connect a bluetooth speaker, the proactive app suggestions show up as they did in iOS 9!

I found the basics of this procedure in the comments at [this reddit discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/53sdbw/ios_10_no_longer_recognises_plugging_in).

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by jefe2000 is only partially correct.

To receive the Proactive App Suggestions in the bottom left corner of the lock screen, in the App Switcher and in Spotlight, the following are **required**.

1. Frequent Locations in **Settings** > **Privacy** > **Location Services** > **System Services** > **Frequent Locations** is turned on.
2. The Siri App Suggestions widget is enabled.
3. Siri Suggestions in **Settings** > **General** > **Spotlight Search** is turned on.

The following are **recommended** for better predictions:

1. WiFi on.
2. Bluetooth on.
3. Location Services on.
4. Location-based Alerts **Settings** >
   **Privacy** > **Location Services** > **System Services** is on.

I wrote this code so this is how I know.